# Is it possible to download a URL directly into Dropbox's cloud storage, without having Dropbox on localhost?

Tags: dropbox

Suppose I have a file on a url such as `foo.com/MyFile.tar.gz`.

I want to put this file  into my Dropbox web storage, but **without** first downloading to `localhost` and then uploading. 
Note that my localhost does not have the `Dropbox` client installed, and I do not wish to have `Dropbox` stuff available locally, outside of the web  browser.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you go on certain websites, they allow you to save the file to your dropbox. You would need to set up something like this to be able to save directly to your dropbox.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly answering your question, but you don't need to have a client locally available in order to upload a file on DropBox. You can upload the file directly using the browser - so download it to localhost and then upload it through the browser.

To answer your question, AFAIK, there is no way to do that.

Comment: BTW - I did try to use the browser and then provided the path to a file on the Internet in the browse box. It first downloaded it automatically and then uploaded it. So, again, no I don't think it can do what you need it to do.

Comment: Tangentially related question: I wonder if we can get some kind of shell access to Dropbox storage. Also, have 10 points to help you make comments. :P

Comment: that would be cool - i wouldn't know where to begin looking for this other than asking Dropbox directly.